# Create file without extension

Tags: java, file

How to create file without extension in directory with neighbor folder with same name?
See below three examples.
Example 1.

```
package ru;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWOExtension {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "C:\\1";

        File f = new File(path);
        try {
            boolean  i = f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It creates file "1" without extension and prints true.
Example 2.

```
package ru;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWOExtension {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "C:\\1";

        File f = new File(path);
        boolean  i = f.mkdir();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

It creates folder "1" and prints true.
Example 3.

```
public class FileWOExtension {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "C:\\1";

        File f = new File(path);
        try {
            boolean  i = f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File folder = new File(path);
        boolean  i = f.mkdir();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

It creates file "1" without extension, does NOT create folder "1" and prints true, false. And vice versa, If I create folder 1, then I cant create file file "1" without extension.
My question is how to avoid this?

Comment: Um, in example 3 you're trying to create a file and a folder with the same name. You can't do that, no matter what it's called and no matter where it is.

Comment: Files and folders are always File object... then you'll get to create new File("1")... how can you distinguish if it is the File or the Folder?

As Jon Skeet says there is not way you can do it. Try create a file and a folder in a windows... it will not let you either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. any particular name can exist only ONCE in a directory. if there's a file named `1` already, then you cannot also create a directory named `1` as well, and vice versa.

e.g. if this was possible, then what should happen if you try `fopen('/path/to/stuff/1')`, and you have BOTH a directory and file with the same name? which one should get opened?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that file system can't create folder and file with same name.